# My custom javascript is conflict with sharepoint javascript (sharepoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using custom javascript file([mootools-1.2-core.js][1]) in custom application page in sharepoint(2010).I get **type mismatch  error** in wpadder.js(Sharepoint Javascript file which resides in 14/layouts).Could anyone provide a solution for this issue ?

Comment: For the record, this also happens in SharePoint 2013. How was three years not enough to fix this?..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a google search for type mismatch error wpadder.js - first link = http://labs.steveottenad.com/type-mismatch-on-wpadder-js/

Comment: That link actually doesn't help because it proposes to modify mootools to "fix" the issue.  I get the same issue with jQuery as well.  It breaks the web part toolbar at the top of SharePoint 2010 pages.  Looking into a solution and will keep this posted, but the first link is not a solution for third party libs.

Comment: The problem is scoping of variables if I recall correctly. And with javascript's globals scope you really only have two choices, alter the third party libraries or the sharepoint libraries. I'd advise against the sharepoint libraries for fear of cascading issue.s

Comment: From what I've found, it's not an issue with scoping of variables, but rather Microsoft's liberal use of for/in loops which causes the issue.  Indeed, walking through wpadder.debug.js, I can find the line where it fails and it's a for/in loop that iterates over an array.  It should only return numeric values, but what happens -- at least in the case of jQuery -- is that it also returns a string value "indexOf" as an index.  ExtJs users also experience the same issue: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?101262-Array.prototype-indexOf-remove-modifications

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question today because I had the same error. The link pointed by Brian Brinley (http://labs.steveottenad.com/type-mismatch-on-wpadder-js/) actually helped, because it mentions that:

> Sharepoint (and possibly IE in general) has issues with any
>   plugins/scripts that try to extend the Array Prototype.

**The code I was working on had extended** `Array.prototype` **to include an** `indexOf` **method.**

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, start) {
        for (var i = (start || 0); i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**The error in** `wpadder.js` **disappeared as soon as I removed the above bit from the code.**

As a substitute for the `indexOf` method, I wrote this:

```
// this function returns the index of the first occurrence 
// of the given item in a simple array
function indexOf(array, item, start) {
    for (var i = (start || 0); i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === item) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and replaced all `array.indexOf(item)` in the code with `indexOf(array, item)`.